# Construction of bijective map $f:X\mapsto \mathbb{R}$

Tags: metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Is it possible to construct a bijective continuous  map $f(X,d)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$. I think it is not possible.Could any one help me to give me hints.

Comment: What about $X=\{0\}$? Or any countable metric space, say.

Comment: what is $X$, what is $d$? Can they be anything? Can they be $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$?

Comment: @mathemagician $X,d$ can be anything.

Comment: then how about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: If $X$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @AnindyaGhatak If you ask whether, in general, any metric space can be sent bijectively and continuously onto $\mathbb{R}$, this is obviously wrong. See my comment above. If it is not what you meant to ask, please clarify your question.

Comment: @julien I asked for any metric space.could you tell me why it is obviously wrong

Comment: Because, for instance, there is no bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and a countable set. As $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. Not even talking about continuity. And there exist countable metric spaces. $\{0\}$ is an example. $\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{Q}$, with the usual distance, are less trivial examples.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two kinds of counterexample to this statement.

The first kind arises from the failure to find some bijective map of sets $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a set for which some metric $d$ has been defined. This is an issue of cardinality, since here $X$ can really be any set under the sun.

I should point out here that any set possesses at least one metric- $d(x,y) = 1$ when $x \neq y$ and $d(x,x) = 0$. This metrizes the discrete topology on $X$, namely the topology where every point (singleton) is an open set.

The second kind of counterexample arises from the failure to find some continuous bijective map. Suppose, for instance, that I knew ahead of time that $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$ had the same cardinality; I could then ask whether $(X,d)$ could be mapped bijectively and continuously to $\mathbb{R}$. This is not the case, however, as there are no restrictions on the 'wildness' of the metric $d$.

You can create a host of counterexamples, but here's one that's rather damning: let $[0,1]$ and give $X$ the topology $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that a continuous, bijective map $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ could be found. Then the image of $X$ is a compact set by continuity, and since $f$ is onto, this implies that $\mathbb{R}$ is compact. This is a contradiction. Notice also that we didn't even use injectivity, only surjectivity of the map $f$. I should caution that this isn't a great counterexample, however, because to be fair there are far more fundamental reasons why this should not be the case without stringent conditions on $(X,d)$.